# for any $a,b\in K$ , the ideal generated by the polynomial $x-a$ and $y-a$ is maximal in $K[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $K$ be afield and $K[x,y]$ be the the polynomial ring the two variable x,y with co-efficient from K.Prove that for any $a,b\in K$ , the ideal generated by the polynomial $x-a$ and $y-a$ is maximal .

My solution : Let $I=<x-a,y-b>$ . Then we define a map $\phi:K[x,y]\rightarrow K$ given by $\phi(f(x,y))=f(a,b) $ . This map is certainly ring homomorphism .

It is onto because for any $r\in K$ we have $\phi(x-a+r)=a $ .
The kernel has $x-a$ and $y-b$ in it . So $I\subset \ker\phi$ . Now let $h(x,y)\in \ker\phi$ . Then write $h(x,y)=q(x,y)(x-a)+q'(x,y)(y-b)+r(x,y)$ . From here we see that $r(a,b)=h(a,b)=0 $ . As $r$ is of degree 1 $r(x)=0$. 
So $\ker\phi=I$ .

So by first isomorphism theorem $K[x,y]/I \cong K$ . So $I$ is maximal .Is this a correct proof . Provide alternative solution if you have any . Thank you .

Comment: The idea of the proof is basically correct, but I don't understand how you conclude that the degree of $r$ is 1 and how does this imply that $r=0$.

Comment: There's a typo: $\phi(x-a+r)=r$, not $a$. I don't see either on what grounds you assert that $\deg r(x,y)=1$.

Comment: The degree of $r$ should be $0$. You could add an explanation of how you get $r$ by using polynomial long division twice, which works since you're dividing by monic polynomials $x-a$ and $y-b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove $\ker\phi\subset I$, you can use *Taylor's formula* for polynomials (which is an exact formula): 
$$h(x,y)=\:\stackrel{=\;0}{h(0,0)}+h'_x(a,b)(x-a)+h'_y(a,b)(y-b)+h''_{x^2}(a,b)(x-a)^2+2h''_{xy}(a,b)(x-a)(y-b)+h''_{y^2}(a,b)(y-b)^2+\dotsm,$$
which proves $h(x,y)\in \langle x-a,y-b\rangle$.

Comment: Nice and elementary idea. +1

Answer (score 2):

To clean it up let $I = \langle x-a,y-b\rangle$ and $\varphi : K[x,y] \to K$ given by $p \mapsto p(a,b)$. $\varphi$ is obviously epi since it maps constant polynomials to constant polynomials. It is also obvious that $I \subset \text{ker }\varphi$. For $p \in \text{ker }\varphi$ we can show that $p\in I$ as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
 p & = & \sum c_{ij}x^iy^j \\
& = & \sum c_{ij}(x-a+a)^i(y-b+b)^j\\
& = &\sum c_{ij}a^ib^j \text{ mod }I\\
& = & p(a,b) \text{ mod } I\\
& = & 0 \text{ mod } I.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: This is nice and I will upvote it, yet the step from the second line to the third one may be quite a hard bone to crack for someone asking such an elementary question. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio makes sense. A hint for the reader $(x-a+a)^i = (x-a)^i +i(x-a)^{i-1}a+ \cdots + a^i = a^i \text{ mod }I$. Too lazy to edit the post ;)